# SHCreateStreamOnFileEx linker error

Tags: .net, c++, model-view-controller, visual-c++, msdn

I am getting linker error while working on SHCreateStreamOnFileEx.
Please help me to find out the problem.

```
IStream* replace::GetStream()
{ 
LPCWSTR pszFile=L"D:\\Test\\output.txt";
IStream* dataStream = NULL;
if (dataStream == NULL)
 {
    SHCreateStreamOnFileEx(pszFile, 
        STGM_READ|STGM_SHARE_DENY_NONE|STGM_DELETEONRELEASE,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 
        FALSE, 
        NULL, 
        &dataStream);
 }
return dataStream;
}
```

Error: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__SHCreateStreamOnFileEx@24 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall replace::GetStream(void)" (?GetStream@replace@@QAEXXZ)    replace.obj replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the matching LIB file to your project settings should do the trick. Open the project **settings** -> **linker** -> **input** -> **additional dependencies** and add the `Shlwapi.lib` to the list.

As an alternative you can also put the following directive into your cpp file:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib");
```